# Best way to send apache-spark loggin to redis/logstash on an Amazon EMR cluster

Tags: apache-spark, log4j, slf4j, logback

I spark-submit jobs on an Amazon EMR cluster.  I'd like all spark logging to be sent to redis/logstash.  What is the proper way to configure spark under EMR to do this?

- Keep log4j: Add a bootstrap action to modify /home/hadoop/spark/conf/log4j.properties to add an appender? However, this file already contains a lot of stuff and is a symlink to hadoop conf file. I don't want to fiddle too much with that as it already contains some rootLoggers. Which appender would do best? ryantenney/log4j-redis-appender + logstash/log4j-jsonevent-layout OR pavlobaron/log4j2redis ?
- Migrate to slf4j+logback: Exclude slf4j-log4j12 from spark-core, add log4j-over-slf4j ... and use a logback.xml with a com.cwbase.logback.RedisAppender?  Looks like this will be problematic with dependencies. Will it hide log4j.rootLoggers already defined in log4j.properties?
- Anything else I missed?

What are your thoughts on this?

**Update**

Looks like I can't get second option to work.  Running tests is just fine but using spark-submit (with --conf spark.driver.userClassPathFirst=true) always end up with the dreaded "Detected both log4j-over-slf4j.jar AND slf4j-log4j12.jar on the class path, preempting StackOverflowError."

Comment: I was about to go down the log4j-over-slf4j route.  I think you've saved me some time.

Comment: I think there is no way around it since it load spark binaries side by side with our fat-jar and spark uses slf4j-log4j12.  I've been trying all sort of things today to get this to work but didn't succeed.  If you still want to give it a shot, keep me posted on your findings.

Comment: any way to get around this? major libraries like storm and spark are being packed with a default lib.

Answer (score -1):

I would setup an extra daemon for that on the cluster.